# Interpretaton of Chi-square test results

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm exploring the result of my experiment (in R), where the outcome can be presented as 5x4 contingency table. I've run the chi-squared test of independence and it gives the p.value well below .05, meaning there is a relationship between treatment and outcome.

```
x = structure(c(17479L, 256L, 1332L, 66L, 1919L, 4242L, 87L, 394L, 
            26L, 761L, 6359L, 40L, 349L, 22L, 823L, 5666L, 75L, 325L, 39L, 
            809L),
          .Dim = 5:4,
          .Dimnames = list(c("G1.G0", "early.S", "S","late.S.G2", "G2.M"),
                           row.names = c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", "Treatment3")),
          class = "table")
ch.t = chisq.test(x)
ch.t
ch.t$residuals
```

Output

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test
data:  x
X-squared = 236.55, df = 12, p-value < 2.2e-16

               row.names
               Control Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
  G1.G0      1.3744793 -4.2432348  1.5180210 -0.2012234
  early.S    1.3854929  3.2597551 -4.8551234 -0.2396874
  S          2.9011770  4.0127320 -4.4966957 -3.9322811
  late.S.G2 -1.4033400  1.2079478 -1.1821301  2.6092210
  G2.M      -6.1967331  7.5868936  0.9130591  3.0832144
```

I am stuck with the "pair-wise" comparisons. For example, how can I say whether Treatment1 has statistically significant effect on outcome "S" in comparison with the Control? Should I run the chi-test for each pair of treatments or there is a way to "extract" the answer from this single test?

Comment: The `chisq.test` function offers a global test / goodness of fit measure of the general relationship between the two variables. It doesn't offer dedicated pairwise tests to test for significant differences between certain groups.

Comment: Depending on the type of your data (e.g. counts or proportions or means...) different pairwise tests exist and are more appropriate.

Comment: @deschen, my data is counts (of course can be converted in proportions). Could you suggest a better option for the pair-wise comparison?

Answer (score 0):

With `chisq.posthoc.test` package `install.packages("chisq.posthoc.test")` you can perform post hoc analysis based on residuals of Pearson's Chisquared Test for Count Data based on T. Mark Beasley & Randall E. Schumacker (1995) <doi: 10.1080/00220973.1995.9943797>.

Interpretation: There is a significant correlation between G1.G0 and Control, Treatment1, Treatment2 but not with Treatment3.

```
Dimension        Control    Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
G1.G0   p-Value  0.000063   0.000000   0.001368   1.0000000
```

In other words Control, Treatment1, Treatment2 all have a significant effect on G1.G0. But Treatment3 does not have a significant effect on G1.G0.

```
x = structure(c(17479L, 256L, 1332L, 66L, 1919L, 4242L, 87L, 394L, 
                26L, 761L, 6359L, 40L, 349L, 22L, 823L, 5666L, 75L, 325L, 39L, 
                809L),
              .Dim = 5:4,
              .Dimnames = list(c("G1.G0", "early.S", "S","late.S.G2", "G2.M"),
                               row.names = c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", "Treatment3")),
              class = "table")
ch.t = chisq.test(x)
ch.t
ch.t$residuals

library(chisq.posthoc.test)

chisq.posthoc.test(x)

   Dimension     Value   Control Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
1      G1.G0 Residuals  4.662387 -10.799208   3.981811 -0.5225417
2      G1.G0  p values  0.000063   0.000000   0.001368  1.0000000
3    early.S Residuals  1.995708   3.522918  -5.407864 -0.2643080
4    early.S  p values  0.919313   0.008536   0.000001  1.0000000
5          S Residuals  4.282599   4.444246  -5.132860 -4.4437546
6          S  p values  0.000369   0.000176   0.000006  0.0001770
7  late.S.G2 Residuals -2.013868   1.300592  -1.311795  2.8664955
8  late.S.G2  p values  0.880468   1.000000   1.000000  0.0830090
9       G2.M Residuals -9.382259   8.618532   1.068996  3.5737213
10      G2.M  p values  0.000000   0.000000   1.000000  0.0070390
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however, it doesn't seem to solve my problem. As mention in the original question, I'm interested in the effect of treatment in the comparison with the control. While provided interpretation might have a sense from a purely mathematical perspective, the biological meaning is not so clear. Control represents a "natural state", hence I interested in the pair-wise comparison. For instance, whether G1.G0 is significantly higher in Control vs Treatment2? Is it possible to extract this information from the chisq or chisq.posthoc tests?